# .net: DataTable setting all non numeric values of data table as NULL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, system.data.datatable

Need help to format datatable in .net, giving code below in vb.net

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("a", GetType(System.String))
            dt.Columns.Add("b", GetType(System.String))

            dt.Rows.Add("N/A", "22")
            dt.Rows.Add("99", "22.3")
            dt.Rows.Add("Not Available", "#Error")
            dt.Rows.Add("5.5", "10")
```

' Need Suggestions to transform data table in .net c#/vb

'Convert all Non Numeric Values of Data Table to NULL, trying to avoid Looping and updating each row by using regex

```
            'Result dt
            'a      b       
            'null   22
            '99     22.3
            'null   null
            '5.5    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm if u don't need the table to contain the non-numeric value to begin with and don't get it handed like this, u can write your own method to add rows, which checks before adding them if they are numeric or not.

Otherwise i can't think of anything preventing a loop, if you don't want to use regex for some reasons you can check if a convertion is possible (Convert.ToDouble)

Comment: Gud suggestion let me try and revert back!

Answer (score 0):

Posting working code (vb)

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("a")
            dt.Columns.Add("b")
            dt.Columns.Add("c")

Dim typeList As New List(Of Type)
            typeList.Add(GetType(Integer))
            typeList.Add(Nothing)
            typeList.Add(GetType(Decimal))

            dt.Rows.AddRow(typeList, {10, "23ff", "Test if Numeric 45.6"})
            dt.Rows.AddRow(typeList, {"Ten", "We are here", "89"})
```

The exension methood is

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub AddRow(dr As DataRowCollection, ByRef objTypeConversion As List(Of Type), objValue As Object())
        Dim length = objTypeConversion.Count

        If length <> objValue.Length Then
            Throw New Exception("Data Types must be provided for all Values")
        End If

        Dim _n As Integer = 0
        objTypeConversion.ForEach(Function(t)
                                      If t IsNot Nothing Then
                                          Try
                                              Dim converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t)
                                              If converter IsNot Nothing Then
                                                  objValue(_n) = CTypeDynamic(converter.ConvertFrom(objValue(_n)), t)
                                              End If
                                          Catch ex As Exception
                                              objValue(_n) = DBNull.Value
                                          End Try
                                      End If
                                      _n = _n + 1
                                  End Function)

        'Logic to convert into provided datatype
        dr.Add(objValue)
    End Sub
```